# What does the double asterisks mean?

Tags: powershell

I often see PowerShell commands that use paths that use a double asterisks:

```
Copy-Item c:\source\** d:\target
```

The example may be wrong, as I don't understand POSH that well yet. But I do see examples using the `**` in paths. What does it mean?

Comment: It means the person who wrote the command doesn't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, I believe the above answer is wrong.

Assume we have the following directory structure:

`dbl_wc (top level)
--one_level_in
  --aa.txt
--one_level_in1
  --bb.txt
  --deeper_dir
    --abc.txt`

`Copy-Item .\dbl_wc\**\*.txt copy_target -Force`
Will only look for *.txt in any directory under .\dbl_wc. And it won't look in sub-directories (so for example .\dbl_wc\one_level_in1\deeper_dir). So it will get both aa.txt and bb.txt, but not abc.txt. It would also not get any .txt file directly under `dbl_wc`

Essentially, the ** stands for a directory-wildcard, but not recursive.

EDIT: just tested it with *, and it does the same thing (so `Copy-Item .\dbl_wc\*\*.txt copy_target -Force` does the exact same thing as above)

Comment: `**` doesn't stand for anything. It's two `*`, each of which match zero or more filename characters.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the comment. So are you saying that actually it is using regex style semantics? This would seem to make sense actually, but is there a source?

Comment: No, it's not regex, it's standard [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Comment: Changed correct answer to this one.I replicated the test here and it worked as described. The original answer did not.

Answer (score -1):

It's a recursive wildcard.

```
C:\sources\**\*.mp3
```

will catch

```
c:\sources\cool.mp3
c:\sources\redneck\super_cool.mp3
c:\sources\bluegrass\random\the_coolest.mp3
```

and so forth

It's just saying grab everything under C:\source (including subdirectories) and copy it all over to d:\target.

Comment: Do you have reference for it? Because, AFAIK, there is no such thing as recursive wildcard in PowerShell.

Comment: I agree with @PetSerAl.  It seems to me that ** is interpreted the same as *.  As a test, I did `dir .\**\*.vhdx -recurse | measure-object` and then tried the same with just *.  Got the same list.  Without -Recurse, I only got things in the current folder.

Comment: So, maybe this is not really a PowerShell thing, but actually just sort of an accident that it works and there are examples by linux folks (where I think this does mean 'recursive wildcard') who use it. Confusing...

Comment: It could be, I didn't test it specifically, but in general ** in a shell means recursive wildcard.  I just assumed PS was sane enough to either error out or support recursive wildcards.

Comment: It only works in Bash if you explicitly enable it: `shopt -s globstar`. Otherwise it's usually wrong in Linux too.

Comment: @Fred please don't post SO answers based on untested assumptions... (IMHO you should delete this one)